# Segmentation fault in implementing malloc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, scanf, fault

I am coding a gauss seidel program and I am currently having a problem in using malloc.

Please help me with this. I haven't started with the gauss seidel iterative because I was stuck here.

The error says "segmentation fault (core dumped)."  I do not know what it means. I tried scanning the code several times but I just can't find the error.

COULD THERE BE SOMETHING WRONG WITH THE WAY I USED FSCANF?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//structure declarations
struct table2   {
int k;
float value;
int row;
int col;
int nextK_row;
int nextK_col;
};

struct table3   {
int index;
int fir;
int fic;
};


//function prototypes
void allocate_memory(int num_unknowns, int num_entries, struct table2 *pTable2, struct table3  *pTable3, float *b, FILE* fInput, FILE* fOutput);

void free_close (FILE* fInput, FILE* fOutput, struct table2 *pTable2, struct table3 *pTable3, float *b);


int main (int argc, char* argv[])   {


//variable declarations
FILE *fInput=NULL;
FILE *fOutput=NULL;
struct table2 *pTable2=NULL;
struct table3 *pTable3=NULL;
int num_unknowns, num_entries;
float *b=NULL;
int i, j, m;
int count1, count2, count3, count4, l;



//check if arguments from user is 3, else error
if (argc!=3)    {
    printf("Error, the number of arguments should be exactly as needed(three).\n");
    return 1;
}


//open input file
fInput = fopen(argv[1], "r");
//check if input file opened successfully
if (fInput == NULL) {
    printf("Error. Input file wasn't opened successfully.\n");
    return 1;
}

//open output file
fOutput = fopen(argv[2], "w");
//check if output file opened successfully
if (fOutput == NULL)    {
    printf("Error. Output file wasn't opened successfully.\n");
    return 1;
}

//scan no. of unknowns from file and check if successful
count1 = fscanf(fInput, " %d", &num_unknowns);
if (count1 != 1)    {
    printf("Error, fscanf() did not read number of unknowns successfully.");    
//call function to free memory and close files
free_close (fInput, fOutput, pTable2, pTable3, b);
return 1;
}


//scan no. of entries from file and check if successful
count2 = fscanf(fInput, " %d", &num_entries);
if (count2 != 1)    {
    printf("Error, fscanf() did not read number of entries successfully."); 
//call function to free memory and close files
free_close (fInput, fOutput, pTable2, pTable3, b);
return 1;
}


//call function to allocate memory
allocate_memory(num_unknowns, num_entries, pTable2, pTable3, b, fInput, fOutput);


//loop to read values from Table2 and check if it read successfully
for(i=1; i<=num_entries; i++)   {
    count3 = fscanf(fInput, " %d %f %d %d %d %d", &(pTable2[i].k), &(pTable2[i].value), &(pTable2[i].row), &(pTable2[i]).col, &(pTable2[i].nextK_row), &(pTable2[i].nextK_col));
    if (count3 != 6)    {
        printf("Error, fscanf() did not read table 2 values successfully.");
//call function to free memory and close files
        free_close (fInput, fOutput, pTable2, pTable3, b);
        return 1;
    }
}

//loop to get values from Table3
for(j=1; j<=num_unknowns; j++)  {
    count4 = fscanf(fInput, " %d %d %d", &(pTable3[j].index), &(pTable3[j].fir), &(pTable3[j].fic));
    if (count4 != 3)    {
        printf("Error, fscanf() did not read table3 values successfully.");
//call function to free memory and close files
        free_close (fInput, fOutput, pTable2, pTable3, b);
        return 1;
    }
}

//loop to get constants from file
for(m=1; m<=num_unknowns ; m++) {
    l = fscanf(fInput, " %f", &(b[m]));
    if (l != 1) {
        printf("Error, fscanf() did not read constant values successfully.");
//call function to free memory and close files
        free_close (fInput, fOutput, pTable2, pTable3, b);
        return 1;
    }
}



//test print
for(i=1; i<=num_entries; i++)   {
    printf("%d\t", pTable2[i].k);
    printf("%f\t", pTable2[i].value);
    printf("%d\t", pTable2[i].row);
    printf("%d\t", pTable2[i].col);
    printf("%d\t", pTable2[i].nextK_row);
    printf("%d\t", pTable2[i].nextK_col);
}
printf("\n\n\n");
for(j=1; j<=num_unknowns; j++)  {
    printf("%d\t", pTable3[j].index);
    printf("%d\t", pTable3[j].fir);
    printf("%d\t", pTable3[j].fic);
}
printf("\n\n\n");
for(m=1; m<=num_unknowns ; m++) {
    printf("%f", b[m]);
    }
printf("\n\n\n");







//call function to free memory and close files
free_close (fInput, fOutput, pTable2, pTable3, b);


return 0;
}



//function to allocate memory
void allocate_memory(int num_unknowns, int num_entries, struct table2* pTable2, struct table3* pTable3, float* b, FILE* fInput, FILE* fOutput)  {


//allocate memory for table 2   
pTable2 = (struct table2* ) malloc(24*num_entries);
if (pTable2 == NULL)    {
    printf("Error, memory allocation for table2 failed.");
//call function to free memory and close files
    free_close (fInput, fOutput, pTable2, pTable3, b);
    exit(-1);
}

//allocate memory for table 3
pTable3 = (struct table3* ) malloc(12*num_unknowns);
if (pTable3 == NULL)    {
    printf("Error, memory allocation for table3 failed.");
//call function to free memory and close files
    free_close (fInput, fOutput, pTable2, pTable3, b);
    exit(-1);
} 

//allocate memory for constants
b = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*num_unknowns);
if (b == NULL)  {
    printf("Error, memory allocation for matrix B entries failed.");
//call function to free memory and close files
    free_close (fInput, fOutput, pTable2, pTable3, b);
    exit(-1);
}

return;
}


//function to free allocated memory and close files

void free_close (FILE* fInput, FILE* fOutput, struct table2 *pTable2, struct table3 *pTable3, float *b) {

if (fInput != NULL)
    fclose(fInput);
if (fOutput != NULL)
    fclose(fOutput);

if (pTable2 != NULL)
    free(pTable2);
if (pTable3 != NULL)
    free(pTable3);
if (b != NULL)
    free(b);

return;
}
```

Comment: No need for screaming.

Comment: Run your program with a debugger, it will tell you **where** it crashes.

Comment: Do not forget to pointer that is passed by value. It does not affect the original as well as put a pointer to something that was pushed onto the stack.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a Q&A site, so what is your question?

Comment: Where it could possibly get wrong? Do you guys have any idea? My compiler only says segmentation fault and I just can't figure out which part goes wrong.

Comment: COULD THERE BE A PROBLEM WITH THE WAY I USED FSCANF? please help me

Comment: Don't shout. The comment by @BLUEPIXY says it all. You are passing the pointer by value, the function allocates and assigns to the pointer, but the new value is not "visible" for the caller.

Answer (score 1):

In this function call:

```
allocate_memory(num_unknowns, num_entries, pTable2, pTable3, b, fInput, fOutput);
```

you pass all the variables by value. Then inside `allocate_memory` you change the local copies of those variables. Those changes do not affect the variables in `main()`.

Your segfaults probably come from doing `ptable2[i]` etc. in `main()` because `pTable2` is still `NULL`.

To fix this , pass the variables by reference. However , your whole `free_close` setup is pretty ugly. I'd suggest putting all the relevant control variables into a `struct`; and have `main()` call a function which has the rest of your code in it, and `main()` can do the freeing after that function ends.

Also you should learn how to figure out where a segmentation fault is occurring, it is a useful skill. If you don't have a debugger set up and don't want to learn it just now, you can "debug" by inserting output statements (including a flush) in your code and running the program and seeing if that output appeared. That way, you can gradually narrow it down to which line has the problem.

Comment: Anonymouse's answer is also correct; you are probably `malloc`'ing the wrong number of bytes. IDK why you think putting `24` there is a good idea. Use this idiom: `pTable2 = malloc( num_entries * sizeof *pTable2 )`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `pTable2 = (struct table2* ) malloc(24*num_entries);` why not `pTable2 = (struct table2* ) malloc(sizeof (struct table2)*num_entries);`

Comment: Tried it but still segmentation fault. I really don't know what to do anymore. I think the problem is with the fscanf but huhu =(((((( thanks anyway

Comment: Don't cast the result of malloc

Comment: __DO__ \ __ALWAYS__ cast the return value of malloc, especially if you every any to compile the code as C++